# ArrayAdapter + Spinner

Tags: android, spinner, android-arrayadapter

I'm working with spinners plus the arrayadapters that come with them but I just can't get my head around what **setDropDownViewResource()** does. How is it related to the layout you can pass when contructing the arrayadapter (i.e. Context context, **int textViewResourceId**, List objects))?

---

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adp1;
ArrayList<String> arrayList1 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.sp1_array)));

Spinner sp1 = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

adp1 = new ArrayAdapter<String> (mcntxt, R.layout.my_simple_list_item, arrayList1);
adp1.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.my_simple_dropdown_item_1line);
sp1.setAdapter(adp1);
```

Comment: Now are u asking explanation or u have some error ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ID you are using on the constructor will be used for the Spinner main window, or `prompt`, as the documentation states.
When you call `setDropDownViewResource()`, you are establishing the layout to be used for the itens on the spinners dropdown list. Note that this applies for spinners used as dropdown.

Comment: Let me get this straight. The spinner prompt is that thing that looks like a textfield with triangle, right? I have this problem wherein I've set the dropDownViewResource, the layout is just a textView with a selector-background. Now, when I press on an item, what happens is that the default blue color shows up underneath the the drawable I've set for the pressed state (which is a transparent red). I've verified this. Any thoughts on what's happening? Could it have something to do with the fact that I've added a theme using android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html

Comment: That is correct, the prompt is the clickable textview with a triangle. Have you set your spinnerMode as dropdown or as a dialog? This method should work for dropdown spinners. The theme should have been overwritten by any attribute that you have set in XML. Try to set solid colors as background to be sure the attributes changes are   working properly and, from that on, change gradually towards your desired behavior.